# Passing pointer or array to function

Tags: arrays, c, pointers

It seems like if I have a fixed-size array in C I can pass it to a function as long as the argument of the function is either a pointer or an array with no specified size, e.g.:

```
int a[3] = {0, 1, 2};

void fn1(int *a);
void fn2(int a[]);
```

I also noticed that I can use standard member access and pointer arithmetic with both.

Is there any *formal* or *functional* difference between the two approaches? Logically I would think that the second one is better because it indicates that I am supposed to treat the input argument as an array, but that's just my guess.

Any hints will be appreciated.

Comment: `int a[]` in the function parameter list is just another way to write `int *a`. Thus there are no different approaches to compare and contrast. The two notations mean exactly the same thing, by definition.

Comment: ```a[] => *a``` conversion is done at compile time. Like ```s->a => (*s).a```

Comment: In that case, is there any better formal approach or convention?

Comment: @user3758232 use ```int a[]``` because it is easily understandable/readable. But there is not difference between ```int a[]``` and ```int *p```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any formal or functional difference between the two approaches?

There is no formal or functional difference between those two approaches.

During compilation `int a[]` is converted to `int *a`. But for better readability use `int a[]` over `int *a`.

`print (a[2])` is converted to `print (*a + (2 * sizeof(int)))`.